# Influence of incident signal on antenna S-parameters

Tags: antenna, s-parameters

I'm interested in determining the phase of an incoming signal using a 1-port Vector Network Analyzer (VNA). The antenna would be receiving a signal while connected to the VNA. I know that the S11 parameter determined by the VNA will have an amplitude and phase ([from](https://ibis.org/connector/touchstone_spec11.pdf)), but I would like to know if the incident signal will have any effect on the phase of that S11 parameter, or if it is solely a product of the antenna properties.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A signal being received by an antenna has no effect on the S11 of the antenna, but it might have an effect on the *measurement* of the S11 (depending on what the signal is).

The way you measure S11 is to throw an electrical signal at the antenna terminals (geneally written \$a\$), and measure the signal coming back (\$b\$). The S11 is then calculated as the ratio of reflected to transmitted, \$S11=\frac{a}{b}\$.

If you try to measure the S11 while an RF signal is incident on the antenna, then the measured signal will comprise the linear addition of both the \$b\$ reflected from the antenna, and the incoming signal.

If the incoming RF is uncorrelated with the \$a\$ signal, then the result will be a noisy disturbance to the S11 measurement, which can be averaged out as noise.

If OTOH, the incoming RF is a reflection of RF actually transmitted by the antenna as a result of the \$a\$ signal, then it is correlated, cannot be averaged out, and is in some sense a true measure of the S11 of the complete antenna assembly, as you have it set up to be measured. For instance, consider a reflector antenna with a feedhorn, if there is some structural support reflecting signal inadvertently, that is still part of the overall antenna's S11.